# cast two class with shared property c#

Tags: c#, casting, repository-pattern

My old program uses 3 layer 
UI , Service , Business

now I want to add data layer and use entity framework

in business :

```
public abstract  class ITypeCollection
{   
    public int Id ;
    public string name;
    public int subset;
}
```

and

```
public class TTag:ITypeCollection
{
}
```

and use repository pattern :

```
public interface ITypeRepository
{
    IList<TTag> FindAllTTag();
}
```

i implement ITypeRepository

public class TypeRepository : ITypeRepository
    {

```
    public IList<TTag> FindAllTTag()
    {

        using(var dbContext = new PAMEntities())
        {
            List<TypeCollectionSet> res = (from c in dbContext.TypeCollectionSets
                       join t in dbContext.TypeCollectionSet_TTag
                       on c.Id equals t.Id
                       select c).ToList();

           return (TTag) res;

        }
    }
```

but error when **return (TTag) res;**

error :

Error   1   Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'PAM.Model.TTag'

my  TypeCollectionSet :

```
public partial class TypeCollectionSet
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TypeCollectionSet()
    {
        this.TaggedSet = new HashSet<TaggedSet>();
        this.TransactionSet = new HashSet<TransactionSet>();
        this.AccountSets = new HashSet<AccountSet>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Subset { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TaggedSet> TaggedSet { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionSet> TransactionSet { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeCollectionSet_TAccount TypeCollectionSet_TAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeCollectionSet_TExpense TypeCollectionSet_TExpense { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeCollectionSet_TIncome TypeCollectionSet_TIncome { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeCollectionSet_TTag TypeCollectionSet_TTag { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AccountSet> AccountSets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're getting the error, as that's not the typed you've declared as the return type for the method?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Ok ,I have two class, that have shered property . Id , Name , subset . i want casting from class created with entity framwork  to my business class

Comment: You are trying to cast the list itself to a TTag. Cast all elements in the list using LINQ and then return the list

Comment: @thakrage i'm begginer, could you wirte example, I did not notice what you mean

Comment: I have now posted an answer

Comment: You'll want to construct new `TTag` instances and return the list of those. Whilst a derived class can be treated as its base class, the inverse is not possible without creating a new instance,

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the list itself to a `TTag`. This cannot be done.

Cast the individual elements in the list instead.

```
 public IList<TTag> FindAllTTag()
{

    using(var dbContext = new PAMEntities())
    {
        var res = (from c in dbContext.TypeCollectionSets
                   join t in dbContext.TypeCollectionSet_TTag
                   on c.Id equals t.Id
                   select c).ToList().Cast<TTag>().ToList();

       return res;

    }
}
```

Comment: show error: 
Error 1 'System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context